# Dataset to a List(of Integer) in 1 line

Tags: .net, vb.net, list

I need to fill a List with data from a DataColumn fetched in dataset. How can I achieve that in 1 step without looping through the entire table in dataset.

I want something like this:

```
Dim lst as List (of Integer) = ds.Tables("Customer_Data").Columns(0)
```

However the above line is wrong as System.Data.DataColumn cannot be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Dim lst as List (of Integer) = ds.Tables("Customer_Data")
                                 .AsEnumerable()
                                 .Select(Function(r) CInt(r(0)))
                                 .ToList()
```

In addition you will need to import the `System.Linq` if you are not doing it already.

Comment: got it... but didn't need to import System.Linq. anyways does it have any performance issues?